# What late 80s - mid 90s cartoon had heroes with insect mechs?

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon, vehicles

I am trying to identify a TV show, aired somewhere between the late 80s and mid-90s. It was a cartoon, sort of like anime style but more like G.I. Joe.

The main plot points that i can remember are:

- The kid (hero) had a blue scorpion, red ant and a green grasshopper
  vehicle
- The bad guys and a girl had big animal type mechs, e.g. an Ape.
- Each mech has a big button that would launch a big bomb, 3 little skeletons would say "hear no evil, see no evil, speak no evil."

Hope you can help.

Comment: Cartoon, live action....?

Comment: Cartoon sort of like anime style but more like gi joe

Comment: Edit that into the question then (and as many details as you can) :)

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160125/an-anime-i-watched-in-the-80s-i-was-too-young-to-remember-the-name

Answer (score 7):

It's *[Timefighters in the Land of Fantasy](http://www.anime-games.co.uk/VHS/anime/timefighters-in-the-land-of-fantasy.php)*, aka *[Time Bokan (タイムボカン)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Bokan)* for the original anime.

Comment: I've moved the link into the answer, as well as adding a link to the Wikipedia article. The elements are definitely all there, but I know I've been scolded in the past for adding additional data to someone else's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is [Big Bad Beetleborgs](https://www.google.com/search?q=Big%20Bad%20Beetleborgs&espv=210&es_sm=122&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=ukyZUqfPDoWThQePyYGoAg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAA&biw=1920&bih=978&dpr=1)

Set in the fictional town of Charterville, three "typical average kids", Drew, Jo and Roland, enter the supposedly haunted Hillhurst Mansion after accepting a dare from rich snobs Van and Trip. The house is revealed to be the home of real monsters when the kids accidentally bump a pipe organ, releasing a phasm named Flabber. He proves to be friendly, and in return for releasing him, offers to grant them one wish. They wish to become their comic book heroes, the Big Bad Beetleborgs. However, this also brings the Beetleborgs' sworn enemies to life: the Magnavores, led by the evil Vexor, who would summon monsters from the comic books to battle the Beetleborgs. Roland's mom and dad run the comic book shop along with his grandmother Nano. In a 6-parter, Vexor created his own Beetleborg, Shadowborg, which was a match for the Beetleborgs and briefly took their powers. They had to call a temporary Beetleborg (White Blaster Beetleborg) Josh, and after Shadowborg was destroyed, Josh lost his powers. The Beetleborgs would meet the Beetleborgs comic creator, Art Fortunes during this six part story in order for him to create the White Blaster Beetleborg and the Mega Blue Beetleborg.

Answer (score 2):

As per Ayrton's answer, it's *[Timefighters in the Land of Fantasy](http://www.anime-games.co.uk/VHS/anime/timefighters-in-the-land-of-fantasy.php)*, aka *[Time Bokan (タイムボカン)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Bokan)* for the original anime.

> Dr. Kieda, a somewhat wacky but intelligent scientist, has finally succeeded in inventing insect-shaped time machines called "Time Bokan". To prove its efficiency and safety, he decides to serve as the very first guinea pig for its maiden voyage. However, by the time his machine returned, he isn't anywhere inside. The only thing that it returned with is a talking parrot, along with a large gemstone called the Dynamond (ダイナモンド Dainamondo), which is seemingly the most powerful and valuable jewel in the world.
>
> Now it's up to a search party, founded by Dr. Kieda's lab assistant Tanpei, to travel through time to find Dr. Kieda. However, it seems that someone power hungry is looking for the "Dynamond" as well

His assistant, a 13-year-old boy named Tanpei, had the following mechs:

> - Time Mechabuton ("タイムメカブトン", a.k.a. Time Bokan I): This blue machine, which resembles a Japanese rhinoceros beetle
> - Time Dotabattan ("タイムドタバッタン", a.k.a. Time Bokan II): This green, locust-shaped Time Bokan was actually captured by Dr. Kieda in the 27th episode from a species known as "Insect People", the seemingly futuristic dominant species of Earth.
> - Time Kuwagattan ("タイムクワガッタン", a.k.a. Time Bokan III): This red, stag beetle-shaped Time Bokan was created later by Dr. Kieda after he was found.

### Trailer

Answer (score -2):

Jayce and the wheeled warriors

Comment: In case the link goes dead (as Youtube links have an unfortunate tendency to do), could you flesh this answer out a bit with some description of this TV show and how it matches the OP's description? There's a checklist in [our guidance for good story-ID answers](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9445/31394) which you may find helpful.

Comment: Sorry, not even close. The Lightning League vehicles all had the same color scheme and were not based on animals. There also weren't the 3 litltle skeletons.