# Anime about kids using small cars to fight

Tags: story-identification, anime

This is an anime that looks like it's from the early 2000 to 2010. The plot is about kids using small cars like insects to fight; they throw the cars on the ground and the fight starts.

I remember the main character wearing a red jacket and having a brunette and blonde hair. His best friend had purple/blue hair and had a blue car, and he had a heart problem. His other friend was kinda poor and worked in a restaurant with his family. He was also a little bit fat and blonde. The only female character I remember used to cover her face with a mask; her hair was blonde, but I think it was a wig. She was super poor, and can only feed her little brother and sister instant noodles.

The main character's car was a bug beetle; maybe it was a long-horned beetle, I don't remember. But I do remember it was red and had a name like Tonkat. And his special move was something like the golden burning blow.

Help me find this anime.

Comment: Are you looking for power battle watch car? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_Battle_Watch_Car

Comment: I found two anime series named “Crush Gear Turbo” and “Crush Gear Nitro” which involve people fighting with miniature vehicles, but I don’t know that the characters are as described. Could be worth a look though https://crushgear.fandom.com/wiki/Crush_Gear_Wiki

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15375/what-late-80s-mid-90s-cartoon-had-heroes-with-insect-mechs

Comment: Medabots matches somewhat.

Comment: https://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/ikki_tenryou.jpg for the main character in a red outfit, and he does fight with robots, although Medabee is his bot.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found it.  I was looking for it too but I'm answering really late so you probably found it too, [*Jinzō Konchū Kabuto Borg VxV*] is the anime.

I'm not really good at describing so i dropped the opening maybe it might help, sorry the quality is low cause I couldn't find a better quality video.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Late is fine, people have waited years to get the right answer.  Can you add some details about the anime that match the points of the question though?  That way all the information required for the original asker to decide if this is correct is right here.

Comment: Also, you can self accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [***Turning MeCard***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turning_Mecard_(TV_series)) or one of its sequels? It does seem to fit the description of the tiny cars, one of which is a [blue beetle-like vehicle](https://shopee.sg/-KOREA-Turning-Mecard-W-Maru-i.278772778.6351417287)

Comment: I thought it might be useful to drop in the trailer, since OP saw the cartoon rather than the merch